# SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I added Apache tomcat server in netbeans and when I tried to run that server following error is showed in the logs.

```
Jun 05, 2013 11:38:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 05, 2013 11:39:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\tej2\resources\config\db.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:530)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1471)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

...
...

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\tej2\resources\config\db.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:124)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
... 46 more
```

I don't know what to do. PLease help me out.

**UPDATE** : Here are the Spring dependencies inside pom.xml

```
<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.spring-library</artifactId>
        <type>libd</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Tomcat server is probably deployed some Web application which uses Spring framework. In configuration of this Spring framework is referenced property file:

```
\opt\tej2\resources\config\db.properties
```

but this file is probably missing so Spring framework fails to initialize.

Nevertheless Tomcat server should be running OK. Only particular Web application with spring framework failed to start up.

Comment: The file is there. By the way I think it's nested exception. Main exception is in fourth line. EXCEPTION sending context initialized event to listener.......

Comment: I don't think so. Problem lies in access to the file. Can you post your Spring configuration? Are the file access rights OK?

Comment: I have updated the question. Find the Spring dependencies above. And yes file access permissions are OK. The file is readable as well as writable.

Comment: I meant XML configuration of Spring framewrok where `\opt\tej2\resources\config\db.properties` is referenced. Not maven dependecies.